# Mobile broadband device was detected before but now not any more

Tags: networking, mobile-broadband

I am using a Huawei E1731 Mobile Broadband Device since few months now. I've had no problem with it, after installing it it ran perfectly.

However two hours ago suddenly the device is not detected anymore. The LEDs are still lit on the device but it doesn't show up among my network interfaces.

I haven't done anything special to my computer this day, just browsing the web, using Skype and reading some PDF. I haven't downloaded anything nor have I done any updates.

I tried unplugging and replugging the device, rebooting, rebooting with the device and without the device, no matter what I do, nothing seems to fix this.

`lsusb` does not list the device:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:63e0 Microdia Sonix Integrated Webcam
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0483:2016 SGS Thomson Microelectronics Fingerprint Reader
```

What can have happened? And how can I fix this?

Comment: What if you replug it?

Comment: Of course I tried that. Plugged, unplugged, replugged, reboot with device plugged, reboot device unplugged then plugged it ... etc. etc. nothing.

Comment: can you plug in and and update your answer with the "lsusb" command?

Comment: You did not state that in your OP. Next time, please be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing and reinserting the SIM card, my broadband modem does the same from time to time.

Comment: Tried that already. Didn't help. Thanks.